# Change in URL to trigger Event in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am iterating through some data and generating parameterized URL links based on some conditions like this:

```
finishedHTML.append("<a href=\"http://" + domain + "&service=" + allEvents[eventCounter].EventService +"&day="+ offSet+(-1 * i) +"\"><img src=\"/info.jpg\" alt=\"Info\"/>");
```

I had the beginning of my application checking for URL parameters when the page was loaded/refreshed, and take some action depending on if the parameters were there and what they were.

However, I added a # to the beginning of the paramters, so the page wouldn't need to be refreshed, but now it's not triggering the function that checks the URL.

My question is how can I trigger an event in GWT when a user clicks a link? Do I need to generate GWT controls, and link a click handler? Is it possible to setup an event that fires when the URL is changed???

***UPDATE:***
Adam answered part of the initial question, but I can't get the querystring after "#". Is there a better way than the function below:

```
public static String getQueryString() 
 {
     return Window.Location.getQueryString();
 }
```

In other words, if I enter `example.com?service=1` I get service=1 as my querystring. If I enter `example.com#?service=1`, I get a null value for the querystring..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `History.addValueChangeHandler( handler )`, and create a handler to catch the URL changes.

There's no need for click handlers etc., any change of the "hash" part in the URL will be sufficient.

**EDIT:**

See this code example - it will parse URLs of the form `http://mydomain/my/path#tok1&tok2&tok3`

```
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  String hash = event.getValue();
  if ( hash.length() == 0 ) {
    return;
  }
  String[] historyTokens = hash.split("&",0);
  // do stuff according to tokens
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I implemented History.addHistoryListener, and it is responding to changes in the URL. However, now the function I have looking for the Querystring can't see anything past the '#'. Is there another way to get the entire Querystring?

Answer (score 4):

*(Just responding to your Update)*
Have you tried

```
History.getToken()
```

to get the value after the "#"?